# javascript if-else loop not getting to else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm working through a tutorial right now on form validation, and I would like assistance on why this function always returns the `if` condition.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                First Name:
                <input type="text" id="txt" />
            </p>
            <p> <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()" /> </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function validate() 
            {
            var userName = document.getElementById("txt").value;
            if (userName.length == 0)
                {
                alert("FINISH THAT UP");
                return false;
                } 
            else 
                {
                alert("thanks, " + UserName);
                }
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the value not always empty?

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: It shouldn't be if the user enters something for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does reach the `else` part when the textbox is not empty, but then it crash with error thus the form is being silently submitted.

JavaScript is case sensitive - `UserName` is different than `userName` thus undefined.

Change to:

```
alert("thanks, " + userName);
```

To avoid such problems, you can wrap the whole block with `try..catch` like this:

```
function validate() 
{
    try
    {
        var userName = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (userName.length == 0)
        {
            alert("FINISH THAT UP");
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("thanks, " + UserName);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert("general error while validating: " + err.message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this in place, you would see "UserName is undefined".

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/799T3/1/).

Also, on a side note - with your current code, even with empty value the form will still be submitted although you return false - that's because you need to cancel the submit even:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate()" />
```

You forgot the `return` keyword in the `onclick` itself.

Comment: Wow that was really thorough. Thanks a million.

Comment: No problem, there is even more but I'll just mention this as advice - bind the event in a global `onload` instead of inline. This one doesn't really matter, just more elegant way to achieve the same thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case-sensitive language. So correct the `userName` variable name in else statement as below.

```
  else {
      alert("thanks, " + userName); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am puzzled though as to why that affects the alert, shouldn't at least "thanks, " show up?

Comment: @T-Bone - trying to access an undefined variable is a run-time error in javascript, throwing an exception and stopping execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I think this could work.

```
function validate() 
{
    try
    {
        var userName = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (userName)
        {
            alert("FINISH THAT UP");
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("thanks, " + UserName);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert("general error while validating: " + err.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just pure chance you used the exact variable name I used and done same mistake like I did and fixed since?

Comment: Did this fix it? I just used the exact variable but i hadn't tried the code itself since logically it works but i dunno if it really does.

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
function validate(){
    $("#form").submit(function() {

    if($("#txt").val()==""){
        alert("FINISH THAT UP");
        return false;
    }
    if($("#txt").val()!=""){
        var un = $("#txt").val();
        alert("thanks, " + un);
        return true;
    }
   });

}
```